# Python Pweave to LaTeX

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, tex, pweave

I am trying to get [Pweave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/) to generate a LaTeX file in a form other than verbatim so that I can add a few features to the doc (logo, footnotes etc...).
So far as much as I love Pweave for the ease of use and convenience, I have been unable to do so.

> Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>   pweave.**version** is '0.25'

Anyone would have a lead please?

Example of code (all in Python Pweave, for illustration purpose):

```
#' let's print
[print (i) for i in range(10)]

#' let's plot
#' we import the modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#' we set the var x and y
x = np.arange(1,10,1)
y = x**2

#' we plot!
plt.plot(x,y, color= 'red')
plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created to examples source files from your code base: one is a verbatim based output and the other is using the Minted package for syntax highlighting, so that you see the difference. The only difference lies only in the addition of \usepackage{minted} among the other packages in the source code.

Using verbatim: test_pweave_verbatim.texw

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, color, graphicx, hyperref, amsmath, url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}

\hypersetup
{   pdfauthor = {Name Surname},
  pdftitle={Simple test with Python and Matplotlib},
  colorlinks=TRUE,
  linkcolor=black,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}



\title{Simple test with Python and Matplotlib}
\author{Name Surname}
\date{12nd December 2016}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Just a simple example!


Plot stuff.

<<caption="Test!">>=
#' let's print
[print (i) for i in range(10)]

#' let's plot
#' we import the modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#' we set the var x and y
x = np.arange(1,10,1)
y = x**2

#' we plot!
plt.plot(x,y, color= 'red')
plt.show()
@

\section{End}

A simple end.

\end{document}
```

Using Minted for syntax highlighting: test_pweave_minted.texw

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, color, graphicx, hyperref, amsmath, url}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}

\hypersetup
{   pdfauthor = {Name Surname},
  pdftitle={Simple test with Python and Matplotlib},
  colorlinks=TRUE,
  linkcolor=black,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}



\title{Simple test with Python and Matplotlib}
\author{Name Surname}
\date{12nd December 2016}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Just a simple example!


Plot stuff.

<<caption="Test!">>=
#' let's print
[print (i) for i in range(10)]

#' let's plot
#' we import the modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#' we set the var x and y
x = np.arange(1,10,1)
y = x**2

#' we plot!
plt.plot(x,y, color= 'red')
plt.show()
@

\section{End}

A simple end.

\end{document}
```

Now, use the following commands to generate the pdf files:

1. Verbatim

   - pweave -f tex test_pweave_verbatim.texw
   - pdflatex test_pweave_verbatim.tex
2. Minted

   - pweave -f texminted test_pweave_minted.texw
   - pdflatex -shell-escape test_pweave_minted.tex

Tested in OSX 10.11.4 using Python 2.7.10 and Pweave 0.25.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately i could not make it work with results and all that.  
My main issue is that running my file using weave('file path') gives an html but i need to have a tex file so i can work on it further like adding other files, sections and sub sections numbering, logo etc.
As a side note, I tried emacs also to generate from org-mod but i found it to be not really predictable enough.  Plus I like to be able to use python directly from IDE rather than coping with sessions and long files.  And it does not seem that org-mode reads weave as far as i could tell.

Comment: Does your file have a .texw extension?

Comment: And did you try to run the following command to generate the tex file:
pweave -f tex yourfile.texw

Comment: Now think i understand what my issue is, and thanks for staying with me:  i need to create the .texw file from my python code.  How do I get there  ?

Comment: As you can see in my examples, .texw file is just a .tex file in which you insert some code.

Comment: Insert your python code between:


<<>>=
import .....

plt.plot()...
@

and before <<>>= and after @ put the minimal .tex code to start a document and to end a document respectively.
Follow the example I gave.

Comment: I must be missing something.... how do you get the .texw?
All i could get was a .tex file, and that did work fine until i process some more text with paragraph and indent ('>') or bold ('**') which retrieve printed on my final pdf.   Does this have to do with .texw ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130445/discussion-between-fedepad-and-cy-bu).